# Serenity bdd cucumber problem running in AWS codebuild - WebDriver was unable to create a new instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild, serenity-bdd

I am trying to run my project in AWS codebuild but I still getting error -  **"**WebDriver was unable to create a new instance of type class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver"**

I am using Java and maven and serenity bdd with cucumber and I am trying it to run through command mvn verify which normally works on local computer but in AWS codebuild it fails.

ERROR:
Caused by: net.thucydides.core.webdriver.DriverConfigurationError: WebDriver was unable to create a new instance of type class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
WebDriver reported the following message: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
(session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /root/.cache/selenium/chrome/linux64/118.0.5993.70/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
(session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist

[ForkJoinPool-2-worker-1] WARN  n.s.m.b.PropertyBasedDriverCapabilityRecord - Failed to store browser configuration for {goog:chromeOptions={args=[test-type, start-maximized, no-sandbox, headless, ignore-certificate-errors, disable-infobars, disable-gpu, disable-default-apps, disable-popup-blocking, disable-dev-shm-usage, disable-extensions, disable-web-security, disable-translate, disable-logging, test-type, start-maximized, no-sandbox, headless, ignore-certificate-errors, disable-infobars, disable-gpu, disable-default-apps, disable-popup-blocking, disable-dev-shm-usage, disable-extensions, disable-web-security, disable-translate, disable-logging, --headless, remote-allow-origins=*], extensions=[],

Have you ever solving something like that?

Run serenity bdd tests in AWS codebuild